# Unable to access mounted USB drive on samba server

Tags: samba

I have a server running Raspbian OS. I use it as both a NAS samba server and as a Jellyfin media server.

**Jellyfin**

I have used the following settings to make the media files accessible by Jellyfin

`/etc/group`: `multimedia:x:1001:pi,jellyfin`

`/etc/fstab`: `UUID=ED94-E601 /media/multimedia    auto    gid=1001,uid=1000,users,auto,noatime    0  0`

uid=1000 is `pi`.

This works well. I am able to access the media files from Jellyfin clients.

**Samba**

I have the following entry in `etc/samba/smb.conf` in addition to the default entries

```
[pishare]
comment = Share
path = "/media/MULTIMEDIA/share"
writeable = Yes
create mask = 0777
directory mask = 0777
public = no
```

When I connect to the samba server from a MacOS client as a registered samba user, I see two folcers: pi (home) and pishare.

I can access pi just fine.

When I try to access pishare I get an error message on my Mac client: "The operation cant be completed because the original item for pishare cant be found". I have googled on this error message, but it seems to be very generic so my search did not find a solution that worked for me.

What can I change to make the Samba pishare work?

Comment: Why is "multimedia" in all caps in the path section of your smb.conf?